# ms-access "show page margins" property

Tags: ms-access

does anyone know what this property does? i am tweaking it and i dont see anything changing on the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to improve your questions. You didn't say what version of Access you're using, nor the context in which you're encountering it (report properties).

I guessed that you were using A2007 or A2010, and checked the properties of a report in A2007, and yes, that property is there.

With a little experimenting, it became obvious that it controls whether or not the page margins are displayed in layout view. It is true that there's not help topic for it, which seems like a bad thing to me, but it's pretty easy to figure it out.

Did you not try anything at all to answer the question?

Comment: Why is this correct answer to a lazy question being voted down?

Comment: Because, apparently, every answer gets a point, which devalues the whole point system.

Comment: It is a little obscure to have a property limited to Layout View.

Comment: Layout view was new in A2007, so perhaps there were some rough edges. I didn't try firing up A2010 to see if the Help file is hooked up there.